# jQuery scroll bind does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html page. Why does alert not working when I scroll the mouse?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


      <script>
      $(window).scroll(function(){
                alert("scrolling");
            });
      </script>
     </head>
     <body>

     </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT: It works when page has the scroll bar on the right side and when scroll moves the page down. But I want it to work on empty page, for instance.

EDIT2: I have changed document.body to window but have the same problem.

EDIT3: So, i have come to result that  I want to catch mouse wheel event

Comment: Have you tried binding to both body as well as html? $("body, html")

Comment: I've tried it, no result

Comment: How are you supposed to scroll an empty page? %-(

Comment: I do not want to scroll an empty page, i want catch that scrolling event!!!

Comment: no page content = no scroll event :|

Comment: ok I got you: I answered you editing my previous answer. See the code in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the body but the window.
However I would put it after the document is ready.
Here's a working code:

```
    $(document).ready( function ()
    {
        console.log('ready');
        $(window).scroll( function ()
        {
            console.log('scroll');
        });
    });
```

**In answer to your edit 3**
To catch the mouse wheel event use the jquery mousewheel_plugin see this [example](http://www.ogonek.net/mousewheel/jquery-demo.html)

So your code would be

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery_mousewheel_plugin.js"></script>
<script>

    var intOverallDelta = 0;

    $(document).ready( function ()
    {
        console.log('ready');
        $(document.body).mousewheel(function(objEvent, intDelta)
        {
            if (intDelta > 0)
            {
                intOverallDelta++;
                console.log('up - (' + intOverallDelta + ')');
            }
            else if (intDelta < 0)
            {
                intOverallDelta--;
                console.log('down - (' +  intOverallDelta + ')');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: How are you supposed to scroll an empty page? %-(

Comment: I have answered you on question comment

Answer (score 2):

Try it on window

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    alert("scrolling");
});
```

Read the manual: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Remove  height:1000px; style and this example will not work.
See edits!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, `document.body` will not match anything...

Comment: That's not true: document.body exists in jquery. Just try `$(document.body).click(function() { console.log('click'); });` .. the fact is that to bind scroll, as requested in this question, you need to use `window` instead

Answer (score 0):

take a look on the `.scroll()` on the jquery documents also with the same example http://api.jquery.com/scroll/